# What exactly did Voldemort do after disappearing?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

What exactly did Voldemort do during his ten year absence?

Why do people say he isolated himself?

Comment: Isn't it pretty clear that he was weakens and without body and powers until he encountered Quirrell?

Comment: While he could not take physical form, his spirit had lost none of its potency...

Answer (score 10):

In Chapter Thirty-Three of *Goblet of Fire* Voldemort describes his time in exile:

> ”I remember only forcing myself, sleeplessly, endlessly, second by second, to exist.... I settled in a faraway place, in a forest, and I waited.... Surely, one of my faithful Death Eaters would try and find me... one of them would come and perform the magic I could not, to restore me to a body... but I waited in vain....”

And:

> ”Only one power remained to me. I could possess the bodies of others. But I dared not go where other humans were plentiful, for I knew that the Aurors were still abroad and searching for me. I sometimes inhabited animals — snakes, of course, being my preference — but I was little better off inside them than as pure spirit, for their bodies were ill adapted to perform magic... and my possession of them shortened their lives; none of them lasted long....